# Need Help Removing a Green Screen, Movie Clip Node missing

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a small clip with a green screen background that I want to make transparent (or just my other video behind it). I have looked at lots of tutorials that feature the node editor to do this. However, when I try to make an input node, "movie clip" is not an option like in some of the other tutorials. I have blender 2.75, is it moved? Is it missing? I am very confused and don't know of any other way to make this work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all make sure you are in the compositor (not the material editor or the texture editor) and have Use Nodes enabled:

[image]

To add a Movie Clip node use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Input->Movie_Clip

[image]

Select your image and add a Keying node. Connect your image and select the color you want to use as key.

[image]

Then just plug that to an Alpha over node to mix with the 3D scene (or other image source).

[image]

Comment: Wow... I was in the material editor part. Such an easy fix, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Cegaton, this is a huge help to my one recent question, thank you.